# how can I store Json query in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have to write Json and I dont know how could i store that query in SQL Server
my code is this:

```
DECLARE @JsonData AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT  FID,  Ftype, Fcount, Datetype, Fregion
                                      FROM FoodSara_tbl
                                      FOR JSON AUTO)
```

and if I write `SELECT ISJSON(@JsonData )` it returns 1

how can I store Json query in SQL?

PS: I dont't want write it in SP

Comment: What do you mean by _how can I store Json query in SQL_ and why do you use `ISJSON`? The function `ISJOSN` tests whether a string contains valid JSON, but if you want to parse the generated JSON and return its content as a table, you need a `OPENJSON` call.

Comment: " how can I store" store *where*? At the moment you have some JSON in a variable.

Comment: in the new specific table or view

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @JsonData AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
   CAST((SELECT  FID,  Ftype, Fcount, Datetype, Fregion
         FROM FoodSara_tbl
         FOR JSON AUTO) AS NVARCHAR(max));
```

Because a query returns a dataset !... You need to specify that the single value returned in the dataset must be casted in string...